# Отправка писем, если заказ больше чем определенная сумма (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Каким образом (или с помощью какого плагина) в Woocommerce можно организовать отправку кода купона, если пользователь купил на определенную сумму?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте такой код в function.php вашей темы.

```
function action_woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification( $order_id, $order = false ) {
    $limit = 999;
    $total = $order->get_total();
    if ( $total > $limit ) {
        $a=1;
        // Отправьте почту здесь
    }
};

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', 'action_woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', 10, 2 );
```

Задайте свое значение для `$limit`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_free_spa_voucher_email_notification', 10, 1 ); function wc_free_spa_voucher_email_notification( $order_id ) {
if ( ! $order_id ) return;

$order  = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$current_subtotal   = $order->get_subtotal();   //current order's subtotal
$current_total      = $order->get_total();      //current order's total

$min_amount         = 600;      //min amount to spend to get free voucher

if ($current_subtotal >= $min_amount) {
    $user_complete_name_and_email = $order->billing_first_name . ' <' . $order->billing_email . '>';
    $to = $user_complete_name_and_email;

    $today = date("j");
    $thisMonth = date("n");
    $thisYear = date("Y");
    $validityDate = date("F j", mktime(0,0,0, $thisMonth+1, $today, $thisYear)); 

    $headers = 'From: Upscale and Posh Flowers <customercare@upscaleandposh.com>' . "\r\n";

    // Sending a custom email when 'Cash on delivery' is the payment method.
    if ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cod' ) {
        $subject = 'Your Massage FREE Voucher. Take it!';
        //$message = 'Voucher code: spa_2017 (Cash on delivery)';

        $message = 'My Msg';
        }
    else {
        $subject = 'Your Massage FREE Voucher. Take it!';
        //$message = 'Voucher code: spa_2017';
        $message = 'My Msg';
        }   //end if - check what kind of payment type

    if( $subject & $message) {
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );
        remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );
    }   // send voucher mail
} // check if order's subtotal reach AED 600
else {
    return;
}
```

}